# eigen values of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices

Let 
$M= \begin{bmatrix}
    c+3b & b & b & b  \\
    b & c+3b & 2b & 2b  \\
    b & 2b & c+3b &3b\\
    b & 2b & 3b & c+3b
  \end{bmatrix}
$ be a real symmetric matrix. Then what are the eigen values? Eigen values should be real. But i am not getting real eigen values using any software?

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial is given by
$$
\chi(T)=(t^3 + 3t^2(4b + c) + t( - 34b^2 - 24bc - 3c^2) + 26b^3 + 34b^2c + 12bc^2 + c^3)(c-t).
$$
So one eigenvalues is $c$, and the other three are the zeros of the cubic polynomial. They are real.

Comment: What are  eigen values other than $c?$

Comment: The roots of the above cubic polynomial. For a formula for the roots of a cubic see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html).

Comment: But using software mathematica and gap i am getting complex roots. Being a real symmetric matrix roots should be real.

Comment: I am getting real roots. Note that for complex numbers $z$, a formula can yield a real number, e.g. $z+\overline{z}$. So it looks complex, but is real. To convince yourself, try any numbers for $a,b,c$ yourself, say $a=b=c=1$. Then the roots are $t=9.26816883714,t=3.44647658876,t=2.28535457409$.